# toggleClass to show/hide div not working with second element

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My goal:**

1. Have a set of thumbnails.
2. Click a thumbnail to toggleClass `hiddenElement` and show a large image inside a div that hidden.
3. Click anywhere in the DOM and it will hide or allow the user to switch to the next div (if that div's thumbnail #2 is clicked).

**Problem:**

My problem showed up when I added my `removeClass` in my jQuery. I think it interferes with my toggleClass, but I'm not quite sure if I structured it properly. So when the user clicks the large image or anywhere in the DOM, it fails to toggle the class.

**My DOM structure:**

```
<div class="wrap">

    <!-- Hidden elements -->

        <div id="port1_large" class="hiddenElement">
            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_content/project1.jpg">   
        </div>

        <div id="port2_large" class="hiddenElement">
            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_content/project2.jpg">   
        </div>

    <!-- /Hidden elements -->

    <!-- Thumbnails -->

          <div id="portfolio">
              <ul class="portfolio-grid">
                    <li>
                        <a id="port1_thumb"  target="portfolio">
                            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_thumbnails/thumbnail_1.png" alt="img01"/>
                            <h3>Project 1</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="port2_thumb"
                           target="portfolio">
                            <img src="assets/portfolio-images/portfolio_thumbnails/thumbnail_2.png" alt="img01"/>
                            <h3>Project 2</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").on("click", function() {
   $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$('document').click(function() {
      $('#port1_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});

$("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").on("click", function() {
   $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$('document').click(function() {
      $('#port2_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});
```

**Notes:**

I have the CSS for `.hiddenElement` set to 'display: none'.

I noticed I have a lot of DRY going on in this as well however, this is currently the only way I know how to do this.

***What can I do better in my jQuery?***

If there is a post that answers this my apologies, please direct me to the proper post, I have been unable to find what I'm looking for.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using combine `document` click code

Also following is not correct

```
$('document')
```

It should be like bellow

```
$(document)
```

Correct jQuery code:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#port1_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
    $('#port2_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});

$("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").on("click", function() {
   $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").on("click", function() {
   $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});
```

Comment: and use a click function that begins the `addClass` above that or stick with `toggleClass`?

`$("#port1_thumb").click(function() {
      $('#port1_large').addClass('hiddenElement');
}`

Answer (score 2):

It works correctly for me

```js
$("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").on("click", function() {
  $("#port1_thumb, #port1_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$('document').click(function() {
  $('#port1_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});

$("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").on("click", function() {
  $("#port2_thumb, #port2_large").toggleClass("hiddenElement"); 
});

$('document').click(function() {
  $('#port2_large').removeClass('hiddenElement');
});
```

```css
.hiddenElement { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

<!-- Hidden elements -->

    <div id="port1_large" class="hiddenElement">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">   
    </div>

    <div id="port2_large" class="hiddenElement">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">   
    </div>

<!-- /Hidden elements -->

<!-- Thumbnails -->

      <div id="portfolio">
          <ul class="portfolio-grid">
                <li>
                    <a id="port1_thumb"  target="portfolio">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32/" alt="img01"/>
                        <h3>Project 1</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="port2_thumb"
                       target="portfolio">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32/" alt="img01"/>
                        <h3>Project 2</h3>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```